# SUM specific column values that have integers where row meets a condition and place in new row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to SUM the first two column values that have numbers where row == 'BB' and place in new row below

**Data**

```
ID  Q121 Q221 Q321 Q421
AA  8.0  4.8  3.1  5.3
BB  0.6  0.7  0.3  0.9
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Q121 Q221 Q321 Q421
AA  8.0  4.8  3.1  5.3
BB  0.6  0.7  0.3  0.9
NEW 1.3  0.0  1.2  0.0
```

**Doing**

```
   mask = df['ID'].eq('BB')
   df[NEW] = df.iloc[2,1:2].sum()
```

I am taking the sum row 2 and columns 1 and 2

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: There's no integers in your dataframe. All numbers are floats. Also, can you elaborate on the math. What I'm guessing is `NEW = Q121 + Q221, Q321 + Q421`

Comment: The new row Q221 0.0 should be 1.0 instead?

Comment: no@perpetualstudent just summing first two columns that have numbers (where row=="BB" , and placing the value under Q121 and Q321 in new row

Comment: @CodeDifferent sorry updated - correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use rolling window to calculate the sum of pair of two columns, then concat the result

```
col=[1,0,1,0]
df2=pd.concat([df, 
               df.loc[df['ID'].isin(['AA','BB']) ]
               .rolling(2, axis=1).sum() # calc rolling windows sum of two columns
               .shift(-1, axis=1) # shift result to left
               .fillna(0) # fill null values
               .mul(col) # multipley to keep sum in alternate columns
              ]
             )
df2.sort_index(axis=0, inplace=True)


#create a column with a new ID
df2['ID2']=df2['ID']+'_New'

# fill NA values with the row above
df2['ID2'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

#reset index
df2=df2.reset_index()

# where the ID is null (our new summed row), assign the ID2 to ID
df2.loc[df2['ID'].isna(), 'ID'] =   df2['ID2']

#drop unwanted columns
df2.drop(columns=['ID2', 'index'], inplace=True)
df2
```

````
    ID      Q121    Q221    Q321    Q421
0   AA       8.0    4.8     3.1     5.3
1   AA_New  12.8    0.0     8.4     0.0
2   BB       0.6    0.7     0.3     0.9
3   BB_New  1.3     0.0     1.2     0.0```
````

Comment: Hi @Naveed let me check if this works. One question, why is there 1.0 in Q221?this should be 0.0. could the code be updated or was it just a typo

Comment: ok  no it is just Q121+Q221 and then Q321+Q421
The 1.3 and 1.2 are correct
thank you @Naveed will check

Comment: Yes it does will try now and mark solution  thank you

Comment: hi @Naveed this works- Will upvote, wondering what if I wanted to target both 'AA' and 'BB' or multiple rows? How would I do this? I tried to change the code but got an error. I did:  df2=pd.concat([df, 
               df.loc[df['role'].eq('BB','AA') ]     .rolling(2, axis=1).sum() # calc rolling windows sum of two columns
               .shift(-1, axis=1) # shift result to left
               .fillna(0) # fill null values
               .mul(col) # multipley to keep sum in alternate columns
              ]
             )   
df2['role'].fillna('BB_1','AA_1' inplace=True)

Comment: I see thanks - it will be like df2['ID'].fillna('NEW', ‘NEW1’ inplace=True)
df2. - will this suffice? Will try it

Comment: thank you I am researching this as well

Comment: @Lynn, updated the solution to rename the ID of newly added rows, not very elegant, but works it seems. give it a try

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list outside of the DF and then add it to the DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['AA', 8.0, 4.8, 3.1, 5.3], ['BB', 0.6, 0.7, 0.3, 0.9]], columns=['ID', 'Q121', 'Q221', 'Q321', 'Q421']).set_index('ID')
new = []
for z in [x+y for x,y in zip(df.loc['BB'][0:-1:2],df.loc['BB'][1::2])]:
    new.extend([z,0])
df.loc['New'] = new
```